# How can I show what a commit did?

Tags: git

A stupid way I know is:

```
git diff commit-number1 commit-number2
```

Is there a better way?

I mean, I want to know the commit1 itself. I don't want to add the commit2 before it as a parameter.

Comment: While "git show <commit>" is the correct solution, you can use "git diff <commit>^!" to get diff between commit and its (first) parent. See man git-rev-parse(1) for details.

Comment: Props to @Jakub: `git diff <commit>^!` is the answer, IMHO. It's what you see in commit view on github.com

Answer (score 597, accepted):

```
git show <commit-id>
```

[Documentation for git show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

Comment: use the option -stat if you prefer a short output

Answer (score 81):

## TL;DR

`git show <commit>`

---

## Show

To [show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) what a commit did with stats:

```
git show <commit> --stat
```

---

## Log

To show commit [log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with differences introduced for each commit in a range:

```
git log -p <commit1> <commit2>
```

---

## What is `<commit>`?

Each commit has a unique id we reference here as `<commit>`.  The unique id is an SHA-1 hash – a checksum of the content you’re storing plus a header.  #TMI

If you don't know your `<commit>`:

1. `git log` to [view the commit history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)
2. Find the commit you care about.

Comment: ```git show --stat``` --> a very brief list of changes.

Comment: Is a SHA-1 hash the only possibility (not a rhetorical question)? What about, e.g., `HEAD~3`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen According to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), you can use this command on just about any object(s). `HEAD~3` should work just fine.

Comment: For some reason, on regular commits, `git show <commit>` will provide verbose file activity. However, it will not do so with a merge commit, it only shows message and metadata. I have to add the `--show` above to get a file list.

Answer (score 71):

Does

```
$ git log -p
```

do what you need?

Check out the [chapter on Git Log](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) in the Git Community Book for more examples. (Or look at the [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).)

Update: As others ([Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) and [Bombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43582/bombe)) already pointed out: although the above works, [git show](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) is actually the command that is intended to do exactly what was asked for.

Answer (score 33):

I found out that `git show <commit> --stat` is the best out of all here.

It gives you a brief summary of the commit and what files you added and modified without giving you whole bunch of stuff, especially if you changed a lot files.

Answer (score 8):

This is one way I know of. With `git`, there always seems to be more than one way to do it.

```
git log -p commit1 commit2
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers by [Bomber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43582/bombe) and [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski) (thanks!) are correct and work for me in different situations.

For a quick glance at what was in the commit, I use

```
git show <replace this with your commit-id>
```

But I like to view a graphical diff when studying something in detail and have set up a "P4diff" as my Git diff. I then use

```
git diff <replace this with your commit-id>^!
```

Comment: What is "P4diff"? Is it related to [Perforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce)?

Comment: Yes it is actually the p4merge.app - as can be seen from this gist - https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372 - one could set up the p4merge app as a visual diff tool