# Get the code of a commit

Tags: git

I am using git on my Ubuntu. 
I have done 3 commits:

```
    --- a/src/node_example/src/pytalker.py
    +++ b/src/node_example/src/pytalker.py
@@ -137,6 +137,7 @@ def action_callback(action,em):
     plot.subplot(2,2,4)
     plot.title("Experience Map Python")
     for i in range(em.get_num_experiences()-1):
+            ggg
         topo_node.id=em.get_experience(i).id
         topo_node.pose.position.x=em.get_experience(i).x_m
         topo_node.pose.position.y=em.get_experience(i).y_m
younes@raoui:~/Images/ratslam_test/rospyy/src/node_example/src$ git log
commit 34a9d3666a9f5e74d97f719ebcd23ae823277fae
Author: Younes Raoui <younes.fsr@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 29 14:56:15 2017 +0100

    ratslam python 2

commit affc341fc2877f26a86e7529296e8e4b344f97f7
Author: Younes Raoui <younes.fsr@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 29 14:52:58 2017 +0100

ratslam python
```

I want to get the code that I pushed in a specific commit, for instance the commit "ratslam python"

What should I do ?

Comment: `git show affc341fc2877f26a8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show what a commit did?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157818/how-to-show-what-a-commit-did)

Comment: It works Thanks, but it gives me only the changed line. Is there any way to view all the project (it is composed from several files)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
git show
```

for last commit.

Or use

```
git show -3
```

for three or for as many as you'd like
(-5 or -n).